# SELECT query not using cache

Tags: hibernate, session, caching, jpa, playframework

In my web application I have a job executing a lot of write queries. This job must run very quickly and this is why I'm using **stateless sessions**.

Thus, as soon as I must update or insert an entity I'm using this **statless session**.

However, to retrieve the data used in my job I'm using a normal session (the one created by **Play Framework**), so that relationships are loaded.

This is usually working fine because I retrieve the data at the beginning of the job using the normal session, and then I update and insert changes using a stateless session (thus there is no conflict between the 2 sessions).

But, I'm now having an issue with this solution. I have an entity that I'm also updating from another job. And in my first job I need the last update of this entity (I need this entity to be synchronized between my jobs). Therefore, when I need it, I retrieve it using a new *SELECT* query, but the entity does not contain the last update!

I assume it's because of the cache. When this entity is updated in another job using a stateless session, the normal session's cache is not updated and then when I execute my *SELECT* query to retrieve the last update, I just get what was in the cache (which is not the last update).

So, to solve my issue I would like to know if it's possible to execute a *SELECT* query with Hibernate, without using the cache. Actually I would like to force Hibernate to execute a new real *SELECT* query not using the cache to retrieve the last update from the database.

Do you have any idea?

**EDIT**

I'm using JPA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update an entity from the database using `JPA` I used the refresh function and it works.

```
entityManager.refresh(entity);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want Hibernate to use its first level cache you can clear the cache **before** firing your HQL.

- Use `Session.evict()` to remove a particular entity from the cache
- Use `Session.clear()` to clear the whole first level cache of your session

However, if your jobs execute in parallel this won't help you, because of the transaction isolation of your database. More [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29) and [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html). In this case your only option would be to set the transaction isolation level to *read uncommitted / dirty* (which I would not recommend).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunatly it does not work for me. Using clear() is making my job crashing because I'm trying to update entities that seem to be detached or something. And evict() has no effect (perhaps because I'm using JPA?). However, using JPA i found a solution (I'll write the answer)